# Create HBox or VBox in android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to make a HBox or VBox in android like I can make one in javaFX if yes can you give me some Code example for the .XML file?

It should work for API 23 and higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linearlayout if you set orientation attribute  to horizontal it's like HBox if you set it to vertical it's like VBox

```
<Linearlayout android:width='match_parent' android:height='wrap_content' android:orientation='vertical'>
...your items
<Linearlayout>
```